# Make invalid form immediately after loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a simple form written in AngularJS.
I would like to make the form invalid immediately after loading. Unfortunately `$scope.myForm.$valid = false;` doesn't want work. Do you have any other technique to do it? It is important for me as I want to let user click the button only when he/she choose at least on checkbox. Now you can submit the form always after loading the form.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.first" ng-change="onChange()" /> First <br />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.second" ng-change="onChange()"/>Second <br />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.third" ng-change="onChange()"/> Third <br>

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="click()">test</button> <br>
</form>



$scope.myForm = {};
        $scope.myForm.$valid = false;
        $scope.click=function () {
            console.log('-------------2', $scope.myForm);
        };

        $scope.onChange=function () {
            console.log('before:', $scope.myForm);
            var isValid = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(value, key) {
                if(value == true){
                    isValid=true;
                }
                console.log(key + ': ' + value);
            });

            if(!isValid){
                $scope.myForm.$valid = false;
                $scope.myForm.$error.checkBoxes = {
                    isChecked: false
                };
            }

            console.log('after:', $scope.myForm);

        }
```

Comment: try using $invalid will work ...

Comment: try using $invalid = true insted

Comment: Have you thought of writing a custom validator for the group of checkboxes?

Comment: I changed into `$scope.myForm.$invalid = true;` and still doesn't wokr

Comment: Isn't there a `$touched` or `$dirty` property on the form you could use to accomplish this?

Comment: There is no interaction to use `$dirty`. I want to make a form invalid immediately  after loading so `$touched` is also wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my final solution, the form in the scope has a function called `$setValidity()` where we can change the validity state, and notify the form. Refer [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), so I check if any of the checkboxes are having true value, then I set the value for one checkbox alone as true, if not then one of the checkboxes with name `one` is set to `$valid = false`, thus the entire form will be invalid, please go through my code for the implementation of the solution!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.onChange = function() {
    if ($scope.obj) {
      if ($scope.obj.first || $scope.obj.second || $scope.obj.third) {
        $scope.myForm.one.$setValidity("Atleast one checkbox needs to be selected", true);
      } else {
        $scope.myForm.one.$setValidity("Atleast one checkbox needs to be selected", false);
      }
    } else {
      $scope.myForm.one.$setValidity("Atleast one checkbox needs to be selected", false);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but how would you solve it according to mine case - with `$valid/$invalid`?

Comment: It is important for me to have that data inside the form in `valid/invalid` property

Comment: @bielas Here you go, I updated my answer, implementing the `$valid` property! please check it!

Comment: @bielas what does disappears mean? can you replicate the issue in the JSfiddle I gave?

Comment: I cant replicate it. It looks like that: https://ibb.co/hqL93k. It is every time when I check any checkbox. And can't click the button - it is always disabled

Comment: @bielas Without your code its difficult to analyze the issue, anyway have you given the name for the inputs like in my JSFiddle `<input type="checkbox" name="one" ng-model="obj.first" ng-change="onChange()" /> First <br />`

Comment: Yes. Are you able to create a chat and then do it with me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154476/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-bielas).

Answer (score 0):

### Try this in your submit button. hope it works

**data-ng-disabled="myForm.$submitted || myForm.$invalid && !myForm.$pristine"**